# Is FSCK on boot disabled in 14.04.2?

Tags: boot, server, mount, fsck, disk-check

I have a few different installations of 14.04 server, all 32 bit, mostly kept updated, so I feel confident to say that they're at 14.04.2. One server is on a clients site, and doesn't get updated as much, I would say it's probably at 14.04.1. During a recent maintenance visit, we rebooted the server and it decided to initiate a disk check.

This prompted me to look into the various methods of controlling the operation of `fsck` when booting. I understand how to force a check on next reboot by creating the `/forcefsck` file in `/`, and also how to set the time period and no. of mounts before a check happens with `tune2fs`.

On any newer installations when I run `dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdax` on any ext4 partitions, the mount count is -1 and the check interval is 0.

This indicates that my disks will never be checked with `fsck` on boot. I have definitely not altered anything to set this. The off-site server, is set up to check disks at a defined number of mounts or elapsed time period.

Why is there a difference? Has updating changed this behaviour?

EDIT: I thought this may be linked to the 'pass' value in the fstab entry for the partition being set to 0. On investigation, none of the partitions are set to 0, `/` partition is set to 1, and the rest are set to 2.