# What's the frequency of filesystem check on boot?

Tags: boot, fsck

What is the maximum number of times the root filesystem on this computer can be mounted before it is automatically checked?

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Possibly related: [tune2fs mount-count: is it disabled by default (set to -1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680980/tune2fs-mount-count-is-it-disabled-by-default-set-to-1)

Answer (score 2):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab:

> default is every 30 mounts

Run this to see your current setting:

```
sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1 | grep "Maximum mount count"
```

I have a [value of `-1`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680980/tune2fs-mount-count-is-it-disabled-by-default-set-to-1) instead of the 30 that help.ubuntu.com is telling me. You can use `sudo tune2fs -c XXX /dev/sdXY` to change the frequency.

See [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=300477) thread on ubuntuforums.org.